# How to whitelist roles from being banned

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, whitelist

I asked this question before, but due to my next to zero experience with stack-overflow it messed it up. So i will rewrite the question with the anwser so people looking for this can have it right away.

So my question was, how can i whitelist role from being banned. Now later, with more experience with discord.py i can tell you the anwser listed down below is the way to do it.

The working code: Credit to CaptAngryEyes

```
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    whitelisted_roles = [728345678923456, 923478569378456, 8923475627893456] # Put the role IDs here
    for role in member.roles:
        if role.id in whitelisted_roles:
            await ctx.send("You can't ban this user! He is a moderator!")
            return
        else:
            # Ban code goes here...
            pass
```

Comment: It will be hard to help you without a minimal working example of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the roles of the user and check if he has a role in a list. I use the role IDs since it can't be changed.

```py
@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    whitelisted_roles = [728345678923456, 923478569378456, 8923475627893456] # Put the role IDs here
    for role in member.roles:
        if role.id in whitelisted_roles:
            await ctx.send("You can't ban this user! He is a moderator!")
            return
        else:
            # Ban code goes here...
            pass
```

If he has a "whitelisted" role we just return nothing and the command ends.